# Excel: Trying to consolidate weighted average data from Sheet1 and summarize to Sheet2 when Sheet 1 has variable number of rows

Tags: excel-formula

I can't figure out how to get formula to recognize variable # of rows for each weighted average calculation in a single, replicable formula combination.  I've tried (and failed) to use combinations of sumproduct / address / match / offset / countif / if / etc.  I feel like this should be super easy, but I'm stumped.

Sheet1 has variable number of rows for each CompanyX/Y/Z

```
          Value   Weight
```

- CompanyX   DataA   DataA1
- CompanyX   DataB   DataB1
- CompanyX   DataC   DataC1
- CompanyY   DataN   DataN1
- CompanyZ   DataU   DataU1
- CompanyZ   DataV   DataV1

But I want to summarize weighted average with at Company level e.g.

```
          Weighted Average
```

- CompanyX   ResultABCA1B1C1
- CompanyY   ResultNN1
- CompanyZ   ResultUVU1V1

Can't get there from here...help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need a pair of `SUMPRODUCT` calls.  The first is to get the product of value and weight for a company.  The second is to just get the sum of the weights for a company.  The first term in this formula is used to check that the company matches (it returns 0 or 1 with the `--`); the second and third terms are for the weighted average math.

Array formula (enter with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) in cell `G3`, copied down from there, see picture for other ranges.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(F3=$B$3:$B$8),$C$3:$C$8,$D$3:$D$8)/SUMPRODUCT(--(F3=$B$3:$B$8),$D$3:$D$8)
```

**Ranges and result**

[image: ranges and result]

Comment: Hey - that's great.  Does the job well.  Have used sumproduct many times before but never in the manner you've done here with the "call".  I managed a painful workaround yesterday but this is much more elegant.  THANK YOU!